# Design and implement SharePoint 2010 authentication for internet site

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I am currently trying to design the authentication for internal users and client.
Currently for internal user authenticates using Claim based which used Active Directory.

Question:

1. Currently for client i create Form Based Authentication. I run aspnet_regsql.exe. Then on choosing the database should i point it to WSS_content or creating new database?
2. How i can authenticate internal employee if currently not using internal network?. How I should design this?. So the internal employee still authenticate using Active Directory by entering username and password using login.aspx

Please advise, how should i design this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspnet_regsql will create a new aspnetdb database.  This database has its own schema, etc. where users reside.  You will need to come up with the application logic (if needed) to create, delete, edit accounts, as well as manage passwords.  There is also a free solution at http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com that takes care of this for you.

You will want to leave Windows (NTLM) authentication on for the zone that you have FBA enabled on.  This will allow users to choose between your FBA login or Windows login.  If you do not like the default auth selector page, you again will need to come up with a custom solution.